# Problem building layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building something like a ListView, but I'm rolling my own because I want to do some custom stuff and have more control than using ArrayAdapters.

So I've defined part of my layout in XML, including one LinerLayout inside a ScrollView. My goal is to bind to that Linearlayout in code, then insert additional RelativeLayouts inside the LinearLayout using no XML, just code.

Here is my XML:

```
            <ScrollView
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/ListScroll"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:id="@+id/ListHolder"
                       android:layout_height="400px"
                       android:background="#323232"
                     >
                     <!--Here is where I want the RelativeLayouts to go...  -->     
                    </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Then in code, I'm trying to add RelativeLayouts, each 50px in height, to the LinearLayout, the one above that has a height of 400px.

```
                //The parent container - is defined above in XML.
                itemContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
                itemContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ListHolder);
                Layouts = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
                Layouts = LoadWithRelativeLayouts();

                for(RelativeLayout listItem: Layouts){  

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40);
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(params);
                        itemContainer.addView(listItem);
                  }
```

Each one of the layouts in the array has a text view in it that says "Test". When I step through the code, there are 10 elements in the array, and all of the textviews are there, so I would expect to see the 400px LinearLayout filled with 10 Relative layouts one after another, each with 50px height (and fill_parent width) reading "Test" - but all I see is one, as if only one got added, or they are all positioned on top of one another.

Getting screenshot now...

Comment: Are you sure that all 10 exist?  Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: @Nick Campion - Yeah, the array is full with 10 elements - I did step through it. I load each element the same way, with a textview that reads "Test". I only see one item that says "Test" - and it's backgroud is color #323232 as defined by XML - but it's only 40PX in height, shouldn't #323232 be 400px in height?

Comment: dude you need to set the orientation of your `LinearLayout`...

Comment: @techiServices - Actually, there was only 68 seconds difference. I love Stackoverflow, but there are just too many combative people here - and you just presented a perfect case of this. You basically accused him of stealing your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add something to a layout, you have to use layout params of *that* kind. So as you're adding to a `LinearLayout`, you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Then you'll probably also need to set your LinearLayout orientation to vertical, because right now the items you don't see are all in a row offscreen at the right :)

Comment: @techiServices if it's being posted while I'm writing and I don't get the notice, yes.

Comment: you do get notified if an answer has been posted while you are writing one...  you also get the opportunity to view the answer.  i don't know what browser you use but it works fine on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `LinearLayout` holding the `RelativeLayout`s.